# Exponential system of equations

Tags: calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations

i struggle with stationary points for this problem, minimize:

$\text{f}(\textbf{x})=x_{1}^{2}-x_{1}x_{2}+2x_{2}^{2}-2x_{1}+\mathrm{e}^{(x_{1}+x_{2})}$

I know that gradient is:

$\nabla f (\textbf{x)}=(2x_{1}-x_{2}-2+\mathrm{e}^{(x_{1}+x_{2})}, -x_{1}+4x_{2}+\mathrm{e}^{(x_{1}+x_{2})})^{T}$

And also if I want local extrema I set them equal to zero:

$2x_{1}-x_{2}-2+\mathrm{e}^{(x_{1}+x_{2})}=0$

$-x_{1}+4x_{2}+\mathrm{e}^{(x_{1}+x_{2})}=0$

And suddenly I stopped because I'm not sure how to solve this kind of system.

Thank you for your hint :)

Comment: Can you use Nonlinear Newton's Method to find those zeros?

Comment: I do not think you could solve it analytically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing notations $(x_1\to x,x_2\to y)$ you want to solve $$f'_x=e^{x+y}+2 x-y-2=0\tag 1$$ $$f'_y=e^{x+y}-x+4 y=0\tag 2$$ So $$f'_x-f'_y=3 x-5 y-2=0\implies y=\frac{3 x-2}{5} $$ Replace in $(1)$ and obtain $$\frac{7}{5}x+e^{\frac{8 x-2}{5}}-\frac{8}{5}=0\tag 3$$ which could be very easily solved using Newton method starting with $x_0=0$ as shown below (notice that the derivative of this new function is always positive).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0.3760062343 \\
 2 & 0.3313943919 \\
 3 & 0.3304499020 \\
 4 & 0.3304494983 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Sooner or later, you will learn that any equation which can write or rewrite $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ has real and/or complex solution(s) in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (which is not an elementary function).

The Wikipedia page shows many examples of the kind of manipulations to be performed. In your case, the solution is given by$$x=\frac{8}{7}-\frac{5}{8} W\left(\frac{8 }{7}e^{10/7}\right)\qquad y=\frac{2}{7}-\frac{3}{8} W\left(\frac{8 }{7}e^{10/7}\right)$$

Using the expansion given in Wikipedia

$$W(x)={L_1}-{L_2}+\frac{{L_2}}{{L_1}}+\frac{({L_2}-2) {L_2}}{2
   {L_1}^2}+\frac{{L_2} \left(2 {L_2}^2-9 {L_2}+6\right)}{6
   {L_1}^3}+\cdots\tag4$$ where $L_1=\log(x)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$ you would find that
$$W\left(\frac{8 }{7}e^{10/7}\right)\approx 1.3061$$ (the exact value should be $\approx 1.2999$) So $$x\approx 0.3266\implies y\approx -0.2041$$ while the exact solution would be $$x\approx 0.3304\implies y\approx -0.2017$$ For sure, adding extra terms to $(4)$ would give something closer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this system has solutions in terms of elementary functions. Nevertheless we can manipulate it to attain something a little easier to work with and get approximate solutions for.

So here is our system:
$$
\begin{cases}
2x_{1}-x_{2}-2+\mathrm{e}^{(x_{1}+x_{2})}=0 \\
-x_{1}+4x_{2}+\mathrm{e}^{(x_{1}+x_{2})}=0
\end{cases}
$$
I asked my graphing program to plot both relations to get a sense of what our solutions (if any) would look like. Here are the results
[image]

So we should look for positive $x$ and negative $y$, both a little less than $1/2$ in absolute value.

Now for some algebra. The exponential term can be simplified a bit if we make the following substitutions:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  u &:= x_1 + x_2 \\
  v &:= x_1 - x_2
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\iff
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1 &= \small{\frac{u+v}{2}} \\
x_2 &= \small{\frac{u-v}{2}}
\end{aligned}
\right\}
$$
Then our system becomes
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(u+v) - \frac{u-v}{2} + e^u &= 2 \\
-\frac{u+v}{2} + 2(u-v) + e^u &= 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
After some more algebra we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  v &= \frac{1}{3} \left(4-u-2e^u \right) \\
  v &= \frac{1}{5} \left(3u+2e^u \right)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Setting them both equal to each other and going through further simplifications we obtain
$$ 7u + 8e^u = 10 $$
This can't be solved in terms of elementary functions, but a numerical approximation yields
$$ u \approx 0.129 $$
With a good approximation for $u$, we can get a good approximation for $v$ by plugging $u$ in for either of the two formulas for $v$ deduced above:
$$ v \approx 0.532 $$
And it's a quick calculation to get $x_1$ and $x_2$ back using the formulas
\begin{align}
x_1 &= \frac{u+v}{2} \\
x_2 &= \frac{u-v}{2}
\end{align}